# pssh, Time out, killed by signal 9

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing

I am using `PSSH` to run command on other machines to implementing `parallel compute` using `IPyParallel`, but I encountered a problem, my command is

```
pssh -P -h ip.txt -i ipengine --file=~/parallel/test/ipcontroller-engine.json
```

And after a while, it returned:

```
[1] 11:54:41 [FAILURE] 192.168.0.112 Timed out, Killed by signal 9
Stderr: 2015-10-12 11:53:41.593 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/fit/parallel/test/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2015-10-12 11:53:41.595 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://192.168.0.115:59413
2015-10-12 11:53:41.628 [IPEngineApp] Starting to monitor the heartbeat signal from the hub every 3010 ms.
2015-10-12 11:53:41.630 [IPEngineApp] Completed registration with id 0
[2] 11:54:41 [FAILURE] 192.168.0.104 Timed out, Killed by signal 9
Stderr: 2015-10-12 11:53:41.647 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'/home/fit/parallel/test/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2015-10-12 11:53:41.648 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://192.168.0.115:59413
2015-10-12 11:53:41.682 [IPEngineApp] Starting to monitor the heartbeat signal from the hub every 3010 ms.
2015-10-12 11:53:41.684 [IPEngineApp] Completed registration with id 1
```

I think there is something wrong with `PSSH`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After googling, I found `pssh` command will only lasted 60 seconds if you not input `-t` option.
So, to solve this, I type the command

```
pssh -P -h ip.txt -t 100000000 -i ipengine --file=~/parallel/test/ipcontroller-engine.json
```

And the command will be killed after 100000000 seconds

**Update 2020/08/28**

Thanks @[Nicolas Thery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903840/nicolas-thery) and @[Setzer22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2475260/setzer22), instead of setting an arbitrarily large value, you can set `-t` 0 to disable the timeout functionality.

Comment: -t 0 to disable

Comment: @NicolasThery Disable what?

Comment: @GoingMyWay Instead of setting an arbitrarily large value, you can set `-t 0` to disable the timeout functionality.

Comment: @Setzer22 Yes, right. After nearly 5 years, do you guys still use pssh?

Comment: It's a handy utility for when you need to run the same command on multiple servers. I don't see why not... Not everything needs to be a Kubernetes cluster. Anyway, this discussion does not belong on SO. I just wanted to point out what did `-t 0` do for future readers.

Comment: @Setzer22 I am just curious about it. Right `pssh` is a good tool to run tasks. That is why I used a few years ago.

Answer (score 9):

Set pssh to have a timeout of 0 to disable the default 60 second timeout. `-t 0`

```
pssh -P -t 0 -h host_file <COMMAND>
```

The top answer suggests a really long timeout, when you can just disable it.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> -t timeout
> --timeout timeout
> Make connections time out after the given number of seconds. With a value of 0, pssh will not timeout any connections.
> ```

Comment: Care to give some context to that except?